# Slowing down the interval of requests sent to a third party in Java Springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an API that I have built in Java Springboot. I need to slow down the interval of requests sent to a third party from my API. What would be a good strategy to delay multiple requests sent from a Java Springboot API so that it is sent in intervals of ms?

Comment: Change the endpoint after every request.

Comment: @TheJet 1 share the code that you have the issues with

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos I am just discussing at a high level. There is no need to share any code for this scenario as I am not asking for any code in response. I am just looking for a high level approach.

Comment: There is not a high level approach when you have a very specific issue that you wish to solve. You already have used some libraries for your project. So we can't propose any solutions if we don't know which library works under the hood and how the structure is

Comment: Well the company that my API is requesting from should be implementing a rate limiter and I shouldnt have to be throttling my requests but they wont do that. So I guess I am trying to implement a reverse rate limiter / request rate limiter. NPM has one https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-rate-limiter and I am wondering if Java Spring has something of the same sorts

Comment: Can you not simply add a Thread.sleep() to the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check out the [Resilience4j](https://resilience4j.readme.io/) library.  This library is built to help do what you're looking to do.

Description from their website, the emphasis is mine.

> Resilience4j is a lightweight fault tolerance library inspired by Netflix Hystrix, but designed for functional programming.
> Resilience4j provides higher-order functions (decorators) to enhance any functional interface, lambda expression or method reference with a Circuit Breaker, **Rate Limiter**, Retry or Bulkhead. You can stack more than one decorator on any functional interface, lambda expression or method reference. The advantage is that you have the choice to select the decorators you need and nothing else.

[Guide to Resilience4j](https://www.baeldung.com/resilience4j), a tutorial from Baeldung.

Answer (score 2):

Add a queue to your API and every time you receive a request don't send it to 3d party API but write it to your queue. Run your consumer for that queue from [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) with time intervals that you need.

Answer (score 2):

The technical term for what you are looking for is **Throttle**.